# Javascript OnClick change various element link colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to change the link of the other link when they are clicked. So example if user clicks A-Z it would change the colour of 0-9.

```
<a href="" id="list_users_title" onclick="document.getElementById('oneline a').style.color = '#414042'; document.getElementById('list_users_title a').style.color = '#B91200';">A-Z</a>
<a href="" id="oneline" onclick="document.getElementById('oneline a').style.color = '#B91200'; document.getElementById('list_users_title a').style.color = '#414042';">0-9</a>
```

I can do it with the colour however this overrides the a:hover which I still would like to use.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that by the help of javascript your are adding inline css to the `a` tag. Inline css has more priority than the one in `style` tag.

Here the solution-

```
<div id='style'></div>

<a href="" id="list_users_title" onclick="document.getElementById('style').innerHTML = '<style>ADD CSS HERE</style>';">A-Z</a>
```

this will not add inline css

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getElementById` you should be passing in the *id* of the element you want. So do something like this `document.getElementById('oneline')` instead of `document.getElementById('oneline a')`.

EDIT

If you don't want to override the styles, use the onclick event to add a class (say, "clicked-by-oneline") to the element instead of applying styles directly. Then use stylesheets to define some rules like this:

```
#oneline.clicked-by-oneline { color: #414042; }
#list_users_title.clicked-by-oneline { color: #B91200; }
```

Use cascading to control exactly how these style overrides will interact.

Comment: How would I style the a:link colour rather than the colour of the element?

Comment: I would probably apply a class to the element, then use CSS to control the styles instead of applying styles directly.

Comment: Also, your `a` tag already has the 'oneline' id, so `document.getElementById('oneline')` already refers to the anchor.

Comment: Hi, Doing it like document.getElementById('oneline') sets the element colour and voids the a:hover a:visited

Comment: This is the correct behavior, given your code, which is why I would suggest using classes and CSS.